# jQuery: hover menu - code cleanup - keep menu open

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-hover

I've searched SO and this question seems to have been asked multiple times, but I can't seem to get it to work in my example.

Here's some code to play with:
http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/w8QsZ/2/

What I'm looking for is something similar to the to the [flowplayer tooltip](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html), where:

- there's a trigger that causes the menu to appear when hovered
- the menu disappears on leaving the trigger
- if the user hovers over the menu (or tooltip), then the popup should stay open

My guess is that the trigger's `hoverOut` should call the *disappear* using `setTimeout()` with some delay, but on the menu's `mouseenter()`, the timeout should be cleared.

I'm still new to jQuery and am unsure where to store the generated timeoutID and where to call it.

***Note:** the same menu will be used for multiple triggers.*

---

***Update:** Okay, I have something working: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/w8QsZ/11/)*
Could someone please help me clean it up and make it more efficient.  More importantly, I would like not to use globals for the timeoutID.  Perhaps there's a better way to store it in the object?

Comment: Google jQuery hoverIntent for your hoverOut timeout troubles.

Comment: I've seen hoverIntent, I was going to include that I'd rather not use it here, but my question was getting bloated with text :)  Thx for the input - my app has a lot of js and performance (page load) is starting to suffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did something like this recently. What I would do is

```
var timer = setTimeout(/*blah*/);
$('#my_selector').data('timer') = timer;
```

I throw the timeoutID in the data for that element and then whenever I need to do something with it later (clearTimeout) I can just grab it from there.

**note** I used this method and it worked for a dynamic amount of elements, which is what I think you want. Just let me know if you need more of an explanation!

Comment: I actually figured out what I did wrong, will you please take a look and see how to clean it up

Comment: I'm using globals, which I'm not a big fan of. I'm not familiar with the `.data()` method, so perhaps that's something I can look into.  My whole goal is to build an in-place editor, similar to Wikis.

Comment: I accepted this answer, mainly because it was the only one :)  But also because it introduced the `data()` to me.